# Python broadcasting message to all clients in a socket

Tags: python, sockets

I have made a simple chat server using threads like the following:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import _thread as thread
import time
import socket
def now():
    return time.asctime(time.localtime())

def handleclient(connection, ADDR):
    sod = str(ADDR)
    msg = sod+"joined the chat"
    msg2 = msg.encode("utf-8")
    connection.sendall(msg2)
    while True:

        recieved = connection.recv(1024)
        adsf = recieved.decode("utf-8")

        print(now(),"(%s):%s" % (ADDR, recieved))
        output = "%s:%s"%(ADDR, recieved.decode("utf-8"))
        message = output.encode("utf-8")
        connection.sendall(message)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    addr = ("", 8080)
    r =socket.socket()
    print("socket object created at", now())
    r.bind(addr)
    r.listen(5)

    while True:
        print("Waiting for clients...")
        connection, ADDR = r.accept()
        print("We have connection from ", ADDR)

        thread.start_new_thread(handleclient, (connection, ADDR))
```

However, it looks like the `sendall` isnt working and sending the message to only the person who sent it. How can I make it send it to all clients?

Comment: That's not what [`sendall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall) does. You are confused by its name.

Comment: @ Ashwini Chaudhary Oh. Its **completely** different from what I am trying to do. Any solutions?

Comment: You'll have to keep a track of connection objects here, in a list or dictionary and remove them once connection is lost. But it is going to be tricky because threads are involved. That said I personally prefer [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/) when it comes to sockets, its much easier to use and maintain compared to the thread way. Example of simple chatserver in Twisted: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/core/examples/chatserver.py

Comment: By the looks of it my thread, solution, code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785969/python-tcp-server-accepting-connections-and-broadcasting-commands/41786133#41786133) may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like what you're trying to do, because as pointed out in the commends, `sendall()` means "definitely send all my bytes and keep trying until you have," not "send these bytes to lots of clients."

You will want to use either UDP multicast (if you're on a relatively reliable network which supports it, such as a LAN or corporate WAN), or you will simply need to send explicitly to every connected client.  The other alternative is peer-to-peer: send to several clients and instruct those clients to send to more clients until all clients are taken care of.  Obviously this requires more coding.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at [Zero MQ](http://zeromq.org/intro:read-the-manual), which provides high-level facilities over sockets by implementing several patterns ( publish/subscribe , push/pull, etc...).